# Get values from link that brought my to the current page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, model-view-controller

I know - the first thing you're gonna say is "Use the referrer!"

But that'd be the wrong answer, and I'll explain why.

Assume you're on a page, say "Employees", that has a search. The search fields for name yield a table of employees upon submitting. In that table, the Employee Name is a clickable object, in this case a hyperlink. That link goes to an Employee Details page. On that page, there isn't really anything, because that page actually loads up a bunch of Angular data from a subpage.

So, the problem:
On Employees, you click on a link:

```
http://localhost/EmployeeData#/details/cc30e1f8-b21c-4384-9710-e927686c925c
```

That link takes you to the EmployeeData controller and index view. The index view loads up details.html, which is an angular happiness full of data. It works great.

But back in the Index view, there's a tiny bit of code that tells the details where to show up, and has a breadcrumb. So in the Index ViewResult, (EmployeeData/Index.aspx), I'd like to be able to pull the GUID from the link that got you there... But when I use the referrer, it just tells me "You came from the Employee Search".

```
public ViewResult Index()
    {
        var vm = _vmp.GetViewModel<EmployeeDataViewModel>();

        vm.Breadcrumb = CreateBreadCrumbDisplay();

        return View(vm);
    }

public string CreateBreadCrumbDisplay()
    {
        var referrer = (Request.UrlReferrer != null) ? Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri : string.Empty;

        var curUrl = Request.ServerVariables["SCRIPT_NAME"];
        //do lots of stuff
        return theBreadCrumb;
    }
```

In this instance, CreateBreadCrumbDisplay just returns `http://localhost/Employee`. And curUrl just has "EmployeeData", thanks to all the real data stuff happening in the angular page, and not actually in the Index view.

So, what I need to do is grab the full URL, with the ID, and pass that ID into my "CreateBreadCrumbDisplay" method.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a possible solution would be to grab the URL params with `$routeParams` and pass it to your `CreateBreadCrumbDisplay` method from Angular.

If I understand your problem correctly reading up on `$routeParams` [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$routeParams) should solve your problem.

---

Here is an example of how it should work:

First config your routes in Angular

```
myApp.config(function($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider.when('/link/:GUID', {
        controller: 'SomeCtrl',
        templateUrl: 'sometemplate.html'
    });
});
```

Then in your controller

```
myApp.controller('SomeCtrl', function($scope, $routeParams) {
    console.log($routeParams);
});
```

Link to it from somewhere

```
<a href="#/link/cc30e1f8-b21c-4384-9710-e927686c925c">foo</a>
```

And finally the console output:

```
{ GUID: "cc30e1f8-b21c-4384-9710-e927686c925c" }
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as I understand  , you can use $location service ,  **$location.absUrl();** And you may succeed this in many other ways even passing your url to action method as a parameter while submitting .